# Rendering Backbone view using document fragment breaks event handling

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I modified my Backbone app to render a large table using a DOM document fragment, which results in a nice performance improvement when there are many rows.

Unfortunately, this seems to break event handling, so that the views for each row no longer receive click events. I created a [minimal example](http://jsfiddle.net/HAZ4G/1/) to demonstrate this.

What do I have to do to fix this?

```
// Javascript
$(window).load(function(){

  var Item = Backbone.Model.extend();

  var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: Item,
      count: 5,
      initialize: function() {
        for(i=0; i<this.count; i++){
          this.add(new Item({text: i}));
        }
      }
  });

  var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'tr',

      initialize: function(item) {
        this.item = item;
      },

      render: function() {
        this.$el.append('<td class="item">' + this.item.get('text') + '</td>');
        return this;
      },

      events: function() {
        return { "click .item": function() {
            console.log('handling click on item '+this.item.get('text'));
          }
        };
      }

  });

  var TableBodyView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'tbody',

      render: function() {
          if(this.options.useFragment){
              this.renderWithFragment();
          } else {
               this.renderWithoutFragment();
          }
        return this;
      },

      renderWithFragment: function() {
          var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
          this.collection.each(function(item){
            fragment.appendChild((new ItemView(item)).render().el);
          });
          this.$el.append(fragment.cloneNode(true));
      },

      renderWithoutFragment: function() {
          self = this;
          this.collection.each(function(item){
              self.$el.append((new ItemView(item)).render().el);
          });
      }
  });

var items = new Items();
$('#t1').append((new TableBodyView({collection: items, useFragment: false})).render().el);
$('#t2').append((new TableBodyView({collection: items, useFragment: true})).render().el);
});

// HTML
<table id="t1" />
<table id="t2" />

// CSS
table { float: left; margin: 10px; padding: 5px; }
table#t1 { background: green; }
table#t2 { background: red; }
```

Comment: I must go snowboarding right now so I can't give you a real answer. Your problem is [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode#Notes): "Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values but does **not** copy event listeners."

Comment: Thanks, @muistooshort! I fixed it by using jQuery's [clone](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/clone) method, which does clone event handlers if you pass in `true`: `this.$el.append($(fragment).clone(true));`

Please post an answer so I can vote it up!

Comment: @otto.poellath why do you need to clone in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode#Notes) explicitly doesn't copy event handlers:

> Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values but does **not** copy event listeners.

So, when you do this:

```
this.$el.append(fragment.cloneNode(true));
// No more events -------^
```

you lose Backbone's [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) attached to the view's `el` and all your event handling is gone. If you want to clone the `el` and keep the events then you can use the `withDataAndEvents` flag with jQuery's [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

> **.clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents] )**
>
> **withDataAndEvents** A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements. The default value is `false`.
>
> **deepWithDataAndEvents** A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be copied. By default its value matches the first argument's value (which defaults to `false`).

So you should be able to do it like this instead:

```
this.$el.append($(fragment).clone(true));
```

Demo (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/M6SvH/